# Apache Mod Rewrite Rest Api

Tags: php, rest, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2

I'm working on some rest api in php. In development I always hosted my local php api using `php -S 127.0.0.1:9000`. Now i need to host this rest api I built in a vps that has Apache installed. How can i do this? Let me explain you the url schema I'm trying to achieve. Suppose my domain is beautifulrest.com. I need the api to be hosted to beautifulrest.com/api/. Here the problem shows up. I built my api so that when a user go to beautifulrest.com/api/user/create there is no /user/create folder but the url is dynamically handled by php with the following code: `$uri = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH); $uri = explode('/', $uri);`. In Apache if i go to beautifulrest.com/api/user/create, it tries to look for /user/create folders but no folder with such name is there. If i want to achieve the same effect I had in development I need to request beautifulrest.com/api/index.php/user/create and now the url gets parsed to the php side. What I'm asking is this: is there a way to use Mod_rewrite of apache to rewrite the url so that beautifulrest.com/api/index.php/user/create gets rewrited to beautifulrest.com/api/user/create and something like beautifulrest.com/api/user/create?user=test gets rewrited to beautifulrest.com/api/index.php/user/create?

Is this possible in nginx too?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

#### Using `FallbackResource` (mod_dir)

You can create a `.htaccess` file in the `/api` subdirectory and use mod_dir's `FallbackResource`. (No particular need to use mod_rewrite if you just need a standard front-controller pattern.) For example:

```
FallbackResource /api/index.php
```

Now, any request for `/api/<anything>` that would ordinarily trigger a 404 Not Found is routed to `/api/index.php` instead.

And use your existing PHP code to parse `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

By placing the `.htaccess` file in the `/api` subdirectory, rather than root, it will naturally only apply to requests for `/api/<anything>`, rather than literally `/<anything>`.

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource

---

#### Alternative using mod_rewrite (`RewriteRule` and `RewriteCond`)

To implement the same thing using mod_rewrite, you could do something like the following. Again, in the `/api/.htaccess` file:

```
# /api/.htaccess

DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

The first `RewriteRule` is simply an optimisation that prevents further *unnecessary* processing (ie. filesystem checks) when the front-controller (ie. `index.php`) has been rewritten to (by the rule that follows).

The first and second *conditions* (`RewriteCond` directives) check that the request does *not* already map to a file or directory respectively.

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* (1st argument to the `RewriteRule` directive) is just a single dot (ie. `.`) so to match *something*, ie. non-root requests. Requests for the root directory are handled by mod_dir's `DirectoryIndex` (defined above).

Note that the *substitution* string (2nd argument to the `RewriteRule` directive), ie. simply `index.php`, uses a *relative* file-path. This is relative to the directory that contains the `.htaccess` file, ie. `/api` in this case. So, the resulting rewrite is to `/api/index.php`. No need to hardcode the parent directory here.

But, if that is all you are doing then this offers no benefit over the earlier solution that just uses `FallbackResource`, except that the `/api` subdirectory does not need to be explicitly stated in the rules.

---

> to rewrite the url so that `example.com/api/index.php/user/create` gets rewrited to `example.com/api/user/create`

It's rewritten in the other direction. ie. From `/api/user/create` to `/api/index.php/user/create`. But there wouldn't seem to be any need to use `PATH_INFO` here if your existing code is already configured to use `REQUEST_URI`?